# How to create bounce effect on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, pixi.js

I am creating a project where a container contains images that scrolls inside of the container when the user scrolls the page. the container it self grow or shrink based on the scroll speed so it changes the css transform style, and inputs transform value based on the speed of the scroll. So as you are scrolling, there is a bulge effect applied to any object in the center of the page (When so scroll up and down it's growing the container div of the image)

Here is the effect i want to recreate :

The effect :

[Click here to check it](https://monopo.london/)

- Here is my **javascript** file :

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.container img');
const containerHeight = container.offsetHeight;
const centerPosition = window.innerHeight / 2;

function updateScrollPosition() {
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  const scrollSpeed = Math.abs(window.scrollY - containerHeight) / 100;
  const bulgeAmount = -1 * scrollSpeed;
  const newContainerHeight = containerHeight + scrollSpeed;
  const translateY = Math.max(-2000, Math.min(0, bulgeAmount));

  container.style.height = `${newContainerHeight}px`;
  container.style.transform = `translateY(${translateY}px)`;

  images.forEach(image => {
    const imageTopPosition = image.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const distanceFromCenter = centerPosition - imageTopPosition;
    const imageBulgeAmount = bulgeAmount / 5;
    const imageTranslateY = Math.max(-2000, Math.min(0, imageBulgeAmount));
    image.style.transform = `translate3d(0px, ${imageTranslateY}px, 0px)`;
  });
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', updateScrollPosition);
```

In this implementation, we calculate the scroll speed as the absolute difference between the current scroll position and the original container height, divided by 100. We then use this value to adjust the height of the container and the translateY value. We also adjust the translateY value of each image individually based on the bulgeAmount value. The Math.max and Math.min functions are used to prevent the translateY value from exceeding a certain range, to avoid visual glitches. The translate3d CSS property is used to enable hardware acceleration for smoother performance.

- Here is my **html** file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Distortion and Bounce Effect with Three.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="img/img51.jpg" />
      <img src="img/img52.jpg" />
      <img src="img/img64.jpg" />
      <img src="img/img71.jpg" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Here is my **style.css** file :

```
.body{
    background-color: rgb(110, 109, 109);
}

.container{
    border-radius: 16px;
    height: 550px;
    width: 750;
    max-width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 350px) {
    /* Set a specific width for larger screens */
    .container {
      width: 80%;
    }
}
```

**So as you can see the script looks good but when i use parcel to see the result i can only see the container and images; the effect is not working. I still wonder why.**

**So instead**, i tried to use the pixijs.io algorithm but it didn't create the effect that i want

Here is the result :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bulge Effect on Scroll</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/6.1.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      background-color: #222222;
    }

    #canvas-container {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 80vw;
      height: 80vh;
      border-radius: 16px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="canvas-container"></div>

  <script>
    const canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
    const app = new PIXI.Application({
      width: canvasContainer.offsetWidth,
      height: canvasContainer.offsetHeight,
      backgroundColor: 0x222222
    });
    canvasContainer.appendChild(app.view);

    // Create a container for the images
    const container = new PIXI.Container();
    container.width = app.screen.width;
    container.height = app.screen.height;
    container.position.set(app.screen.width / 2, app.screen.height / 2);
    app.stage.addChild(container);

    // Load the images
    const loader = new PIXI.Loader();
    const images = [
      'img/img51.jpg',
      'img/img52.jpg',
      'img/img64.jpg',
      'img/img71.jpg'
    ];
    images.forEach((img) => loader.add(img));
    loader.load(setup);

    // Setup the images
    function setup() {
      images.forEach((img) => {
        const texture = PIXI.Texture.from(img);
        const sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
        sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
        sprite.width = app.screen.width;
        sprite.height = app.screen.height;
        container.addChild(sprite);
      });

      // Apply bulge effect on scroll
      let scrollPosition = 0;
      const maxScroll = -2000;
      app.ticker.add(() => {
        const delta = (scrollPosition - window.scrollY) * 0.1;
        scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
        container.children.forEach((sprite) => {
          const x = sprite.x - app.screen.width / 2;
          const y = sprite.y - app.screen.height / 2;
          const distance = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
          const angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
          const radius = distance / 20;
          const distortionX = Math.sin(angle * 10) * radius * delta;
          const distortionY = Math.cos(angle * 10) * radius * delta;
          sprite.position.set(sprite.x + distortionX, sprite.y + distortionY);
        });
        container.scale.y = PIXI.utils.clamp(1 + (scrollPosition / maxScroll), 1, 2);
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this script, i used the PIXI.Application class to create a new PixiJS application and add it to the canvas-container div. I then created a container for the images, loaded the images using a PIXI.Loader, and added them to the container.

**But as you can see it's not that good**.

So does anyone knows **how to create this type of effect ?**  :

[originale effect](https://monopo.london/)